# Matlab - Automatically Generating Results

Tags: matlab

I've created work on a program that takes in an image of a coin and then draws out the face to the best of Matlab's ability (example below). With this program, I'd like to experiment with image processing, similar to how Google Images allows users to search for images and return results it believes are similar.

[Application Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnX8P.png) | [Further Application Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMp5l.png)

For this, I'd need a lot of data to accomplish this and manually using the slider on my application and generating 50-100 results for each image would take too long. So I've decided to create a new button which generates 100 results, each result providing a different drawn sample.

```
function slider2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'Value') returns position of slider
%        get(hObject,'Min') and get(hObject,'Max') to determine range of slider
global coins_gray;
global num;
val=0.5*get(hObject,'Value')-0.5; %Adjusts the intensity of the slider's brightness setting
imbrightness = coins_gray+val;
axes(handles.axes3);
imshow(imbrightness);
title('Altered Coin Image', 'fontweight', 'bold');

[~, threshold] = edge(imbrightness, 'Canny');
fudgeFactor = num;
img_edge = edge(imbrightness, 'Canny', threshold * fudgeFactor);
axes(handles.axes4) 
imshow(img_edge);
title('User Drawn Image', 'fontweight', 'bold');
```

Above illustrates how the slider works, but I'm not sure how to adapt it to work automatically like how I've mentioned.

```
function gatherbutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to gatherbutton (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

%Prompts the user to enter a title for the image gathering process
prompt = ('Please Enter The Image Name (Do Not Include File Extension): ');
userInput = input(prompt, 's');

counter = 0
while counter < 100:
    processFolder = sprintf('M:/Project/MatLab/Coin Image Processing/Image Processing/%s_%s.jpg', userInput, counter);

    referenceImagePrep = getframe(handles.axes3);
    drawnImagePrep = getframe(handles.axes4);
    counter = counter + 1;
end
```

This is what I have so far. So the loop should run 100 times and each time it runs, a new image will be saved into the given directory and should keep going until the while loop is complete. So how do I now adapt my while loop to automatically change the brightness of the reference image and then store that image into the given folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a relatively simple solution for your problem.
I can't grantee that your code is going to work perfect after applying it...

1. Set `slider2` value within `while` loop in `gatherbutton_Callback`.
2. Call `slider2_Callback` after setting the value (simulate user sliding).
3. Add `drawnow` command for refreshing the GUI.

Here is the modified `while` loop:

```
while counter < 100:
    %1. Set slider value.
    set(handles.slider2, 'Value', counter/100);

    %2. Call `slider2_Callback` (simulate user sliding).
    slider2_Callback(handles.slider2, eventdata, handles);

    %3. Call drawnow for refreshing the GUI.
    drawnow

    processFolder = sprintf('M:/Project/MatLab/Coin Image Processing/Image Processing/%s_%s.jpg', userInput, counter);

    referenceImagePrep = getframe(handles.axes3);
    drawnImagePrep = getframe(handles.axes4);

    %Save image to file...

    counter = counter + 1;
end
```

---

Few recommendations:

- Use `for` loop instead of `while` loop (more elegant in your case): `for counter = 0:99`.
- Replace with `getframe` with `getimage` (better working with images than frames).
- Save images in `tif` or `png` format (`jpg` format creates lossy image compression artifacts).
- Use `imwrite` function to save images.